improve my f1_score for classification - pandas/sklearn
I would like advice on how to improve my f1_score for classification. I currently have something around 0.57. Dataset:
lotWaferDie - lot, board and chip on which defects were measured

string values like W02-D12_11,..

XRel - relative position of the defect in the axis
X
YRel - relative position of the defect in the Y axis
XSize - the size of the defect in the X axis
YSize - the size of the defect in the Y axis
DefArea - defect area
DefSize - the size of the defect
dieRow - the row of the defect on the board
dieCol - defect column on the board
xidx - index of the defect line on the board
yidx - index of the defect column on the board
fail - 1/0 what i predict
Here are some steps I've tried
I tried to cut the lotWaferDie into 3 parts.
As for the xidx and yidx column bars, I'm not sure of their importance, but removing them doesn't make a difference
df[['L', 'W', 'D']] = df['lotWaferDie'].str.split('-|_', expand=True)
df = df.drop(columns=['lotWaferDie'])

# use one-hot encoding
for col in df.select_dtypes(object).columns:
    df = pd.concat([
        df.drop(col, axis=1), pd.get_dummies(df[col], prefix=('d_' + col))
    ], axis=1)


# 
Xtrain, Xrest, ytrain, yrest = train_test_split(
    df.drop(columns=['fail']), df.fail, test_size=0.4, random_state=random_seed, stratify=df.fail
)


Xtest, Xval, ytest, yval = train_test_split(
    Xrest, yrest, test_size=0.5, random_state=random_seed, stratify=yrest
)

param_grid = {
    'max_depth': range(1, 40), 
    'criterion': ['entropy']
}
param_comb = ParameterGrid(param_grid)
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
val_acc = []
param_f1_pairs = []  

for i,params in enumerate(param_comb):
    dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=params['max_depth'], criterion=params['criterion'])
    dt.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
    
    val_acc.append(metrics.accuracy_score(yval, dt.predict(Xval)))
    val_score = accuracy_score(yval, dt.predict(Xval))
    print(f"Iteration {i+1}/{len(param_comb)} - Validation Score: {val_score:.4f} - Parameters: {params}")
    
    predicted_classes = dt.predict(Xtest)
    f1 = f1_score(ytest, predicted_classes)
    param_f1_pairs.append((params, f1))  
    print("F1 skóre:", f1)

all program: https://onecompiler.com/python/42antqzp8
dataset: https://easyupload.io/3y2kou

With minimal preprocessing of the features (just using OrdinalEncoder on lotWaferDie), I get a mean CV5 validation F1 score of 61.7% using HistGradientBoostingRegressor(lr=0.3, max_iter=300, class_weight=balanced), and 59.% using RandomForestClassifier(). You might be able to tune and ensemble them (using VotingClassifier or perhaps StackingClassifier) to get a better score.
Looking at histograms of columns, the labels are imbalanced, which usually needs to be dealt with in order that the model doesn't become skewed towards the fail=False class.

Some features are strongly bimodal and have both an X and Y component. You could try engineering new features that capture the '2D' distance from the main modes.
The feature lot_encoded seems to have a cyclical trend, so there may be a periodicity in the lot number that you can extract (this will make it easier for models to home in on relevant signals).
sklearn has some tools for feature selection, which you can use to get an understanding of the key features.
In general, your features are 2D, so using a convolutional neural net could also be effective. An example from your dataset, showing how defects tend to occur at edges and in the lower centre:


Hello, thank you very much for the comment, I used the OrdinalEncoder and now when I iterate through the decision_tree I am able to find 72 and it seems suspiciously high, could it be overfitting? I will try the other things you mentioned

No problem. To determine whether the model is overfitting, you'd need to look at both the train and validation scores (or losses). If it's doing a lot better on the training data than the validation data, then it's overfitting and there's probably room to improve it. If you reach a point where you're happy with the validation score, then whether or not it's overfitting becomes less relevant (as the model is doing well enough for your needs at that stage).

Yes yes i think it will be ok, its test set which was not used. Its only suprise me the huge difference.
